# Several REST and EJB problems

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm trying to deploy a Java EE web application with RESTful web services and an EJB connexion to another Java EE application.
I'm experiencing several problems and I fail to write down every specific question, so I have no choice but tell you all in a row.

1) First, I am using Tomcat to run the app and I cannot get EJB connexion to work. No matter what, I get a JNDI error : `NamingContextFactory class not found`. **Why ?** 
My JNDI connexion is as follows :

```
String hostname = "localhost";
    String port = "1099";
    String url = "jnp://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/";
    Properties h = new Properties();
    h.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
    h.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
    h.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming.client");
    initialContext = new InitialContext(h);
```

2) Therefore, as the server used is not relevant, and as the app I'm trying to connect to is using JBoss (4.4.2.GA), I tried to deploy my app under the same JBoss. I cannot get it to deploy, I have a REST problem: `ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.ApplicationConfig` at deploy time.

2.1) I am compiling with Netbeans and the `ApplicationConfig.class` is not part of the 1.1 version of the JAX-RS api `jsr311-api-1.1.jar` I'm using at compile time. The implementation of the library was changed since 0.8 version, which I was using before, but I had to upgrade the jar because it didn't include `@FormParam`. Until now, I had found a workaround using `com.sun.jersey.api.representation.FormParam` instead but Jersey is not compatible with JBoss as far as I understand.
**Why** is the server looking for ApplicationConfig while it's not used in the war?

2.2) I understood I had to use RESTEasy, and JBoss 4 does not include it, so have to install it manually. But the RESTEasy doc suggest that I thoroughly modify my project my adding a lot of jars, servlets etc. From my point of view, I simply need a RESTful implementation on the server libs to which my JAX-RS API, which is only an interface, will refer once the app is deployed. I may have some serious misconceptions about how Java EE libraries linking work. **Please help.**

So I know there are several different problems here but I couldn't manage to separate them. I have lost so much time on this that I'm worried for my project. Thanks in advance.